# Android Disable onclick for listitem in listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a HeaderView in my ListView. On clicking it, it hides the text and shows a spinner to fetch data from somewhere.

I want to disable the `onClick` after the first click so that he cannot call the fetch multiple times.

I tried `v.setClickable(false)` and `v.setEnabled(false)`, but none of them worked.

Any ideas?

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    if (position == 0) {

            ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.refresh_progress);
            pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.load);
            tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            v.setClickable(false);
            DownloadTask dt = new DownloadTask(v, "Old Message");
            dt.execute();

        } 
}
```

Comment: Provide code what you are trying..

Comment: I thought the statment was simple enough, but posted the code anyway.

Comment: You should disable the HeaderView  i guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably best to just track the fact that you have already done/started a fetch with a member var in your activity and then test it in your OnClick handler

```
private boolean wasFetchStarted = false;

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    if (position == 0 && ! wasFetchStarted) {
            wasFetchStarted = true;
            ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.refresh_progress);
            pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.load);
            tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            v.setClickable(false);
            DownloadTask dt = new DownloadTask(v, "Old Message");
            dt.execute();

        } 
}
```

Comment: This method works I've tried it, but you can still click on the item and it highlights.

Comment: Yes, I suppose that would be true. If none of the other rows are meant to be clickable (which I doubt) you could try resorting to setting setClickable(false) on the ListView itself...but that's probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

how about creating a subclass of ArrayAdapter that has isAllItemsEnabled() and isEnabled(position)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#areAllItemsEnabled%28%29